# YDSE path difference confusion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, double-slit-experiment, interference

[image]

I have been asked to find the path difference at point O.
$\lambda_1$ is the wavelength in medium 1
The answer given is $$\frac{2\pi}{n_1\lambda_1}(n_3-n_2)t$$

Whereas in another question where the entire YDSE experiment is immersed in a medium $n_{med}$, and a thin glass slab of another medium $n_{glass}$, the answer for the shift due to introduction of the glass slab was given as $$\Delta x = (\frac{n_{glass}}{n_{med}}-1)t$$

Now i am confused. Is the path difference due to glass slab of thickness $t$ in a medium of refractive index $n_{med}$

$(\frac{n_{glass}}{n_{med}}-1)t$

or

$(n_{glass}-n_{med})t$

Comment: I think that the first formula you wrote is about a phase difference due to the optical path difference, the second one is just about an optical path difference. If you suppose that in the first formula instead of lambda1 you were given lambda2 referred to the n2 medium and you take away the vector k=2pi/lambda2, I think that what you get is the same expression you have for the second problem. For the last two formulas, I think both are correct depending on how you use them; the first one if you are given lambda in the medium med, the second one if you are given lambda in a medium in which n=1